# Scala - How to extract an XML file included in a generic text file

Tags: xml, scala

I have a very specific (and weird) text file that is not an XML file but *contains* an XML document in it. It's structure is more or less like this:

```
Some text that I am not interested in...
More text that I don't need.

<tagIWant>
   <...>
   <!-- A large XML document -->
   <...>
</tagIwant>

Some more text...
```

I would like to parse this text file in Scala and extract the XML file from `<tagIWant>` until `</tagIWant>`. I know the XML parser is very powerful in Scala, but obviously this can't be parsed as XML.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez I don't know how to start this from a Scala standpoint, so all my attempts involved a lot of Java-esque ideas, like setting a flag when <tagIWant> is reached, then copying every line to a separate file while the flag is true, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is probably best to pre-process the file to remove the non-XML bits before passing it to the XML parser. This code will strip all leading and trailing lines that don't have something looking like an XML tag:

```
val isTag = "<[^>]+>".r
val xml =
  text.split("\n")
    .dropWhile(isTag.findFirstMatchIn(_).isEmpty)
    .reverse
    .dropWhile(isTag.findFirstMatchIn(_).isEmpty)
    .reverse
    .mkString("\n")
```

You can replace `text.split("\n")` with any code that reads the text file as a list of `String` values.

This assumes that the opening tag is the first text on a line and the closing tag is the last text on a line.

Comment: Would not be better to use `takeWhile(isTag.findFirstMatchIn(_).nonEmpty)` for the second part, instead of doing two reverse ?

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez That would only work if every line of the XML contained a tag, which may not be the case.

Comment: I was going to ask the same. Suppose there's a tag like `<aTag>text ... (several line breaks) ... text</aTag>`, then the text would be ignored.

Answer (score 2):

One approach which MIGHT work (in Java terms, you'll have to translate to Scala) is to supply the input to the parser from your own Reader, consume the output of the parser in a SAX ContentHandler, and have a back-channel from the ContentHandler to the Reader so that as soon as the endElement event for the outermost element is reported, it tells the Reader to stop supplying input.

The reason it might not work is that the parser may buffer input from the reader, so by the time your ContentHandler tells the Reader to stop, it's too late.

It's a shame that XML parsers don't have an option to stop parsing with no error when they detect the closing end tag, but if there is a parser with that option, I haven't encountered it. You could always try modifying an open source parser!

Answer (score 1):

```
val text = """
Some text that I am not interested in...
More text that I don't need.

<tagIWant>
   <qqq>
   <!-- A large XML document -->
   </qqq>
</tagIWant>

Some more text...
"""

val pattern = "(?s).*(<tagIWant>.*</tagIWant>).*".r
val xml = pattern.findFirstMatchIn(text).map(m => m.group(1)).map(x => scala.xml.XML.loadString(x))
```

The result is `Option[scala.xml.Elem]` containing your XML or None.

Also, consider the use of `pattern.findAllMatchIn`.